# Which files should I backup?

Tags: backup

I would like to backup every important file on my computer such that in the event I lose all my data I can get my computer back to its "normal" state as fast as possible. I have a large hard drive (~500GB) to store my backup on, so memory is not an issue. Obviously I should backup my home directory, but what else? For example, should I back up my /usr/ directory as well?

Comment: You only need to back up /home , a list of packages, and any system files you manually edited. Otherwise the system files will be restored when you re-install and update.

Comment: Also have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) for a good back-up strategy...

Answer (score 1):

I generally backup `~/` as it contains most program's configurations (i.e. chromium,gedit), and `/etc` as it contains most system configurations (i.e. wifi, sudo).

Just one opinion though.